# nextgen gallery - filenames' character encoding issue

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

I am building a website using wordpress and i am planning to use Nextgen Gallery in order to show some pictures on a page.

My issue is, when i upload an image which has a filename containing greek characters, it doesn't show properly. Actually it doesn't show at all.

The filename on the server is saved as `%ce%bf%cf%81%cf%84%ce%b1%ce%bd%cf%83%ce%b9%ce%b1`

The img src on the page appears to be ok, as `%ce%bf%cf%81%cf%84%ce%b1%ce%bd%cf%83%ce%b9%ce%b1.jpg`

**But** the image doesn't show at all (is broken) and when i click "Open in a new tab", it returns the path of the image, but with the greek characters this time, like `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/gallery/test/ορτανσια.jpg`

How should i fix this issue?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the encoding on the database. Make sure it's set to utf-8 unicode

Edit:
Here is an article for more indepth reading: 
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=328641

[Also taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly)

The reason why I suggest you check the encoding is because if you insert something into a database with encoding set to ISO 8859-7 Greek, then it is going to interpret the characters as greek.